# Telerik Radscheduler Web service call timing out

Tags: asp.net, service, web, telerik, asmx

I have a radscheduler with web service binding set up like the demo on the website. It is working fine on my local machine and also working fine on my local intranet server. When I deployed it to the public server I am getting the following error (Stack trace):

```
    [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 50.62.137.146:443]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +305
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +699

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request) +3298576
   System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data) +319
   Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerWebServiceClient.LoadResources(WebClient client, ResourcesPopulatingEventArgs args) +267

[Exception: Unable to retrieve response message]
   Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerWebServiceClient.HandleWebException(WebException webEx) +311
   Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerWebServiceClient.LoadResources(WebClient client, ResourcesPopulatingEventArgs args) +364
   Telerik.Web.UI.SchedulerWebServiceClient.GetResources() +421
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadScheduler.BindResourcesFromWebService() +90
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadScheduler.PerformSelect() +117
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadScheduler.CreateChildControls(Boolean bindFromDataSource) +81
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +182
   System.Web.UI.Control.FindControl(String id, Int32 pathOffset) +35
   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) +211
   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) +283
   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) +283
   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) +283
   Telerik.Web.ChildControlHelper.FindControlRecursive(String ID, Control root) +283
   Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.OnPagePreRender(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1450
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +113
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4201
```

This only happens when I am using the ResourcePopulationMode="ServierSide". When I change that to ClientSide then it works and the webservice gets called properly. I am using fiddler to see that. I want to use grouping however so can't use ClientSide. Why is this error occuring? Is there some configuration setting I need to do on the server to get the GetReources method to work? Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: Okay i narrowed down the problem to my server not being able to access it's own public IP. So if the site runs just the local network everything works fine because it can call the URL 192.168.x.x/*.asmx just fine but when trying to access 50.x.x.x/*.asmx because it doesn't seem to understand it's calling itself. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is really old, but I came across this while googling for the Telerik Scheduler problem asked by user1932424.

In my case it was an AWS server (EC2/VPC) setup issue. The Security Group I had set up for that server, wasn't allowing any port to make outbound calls. After I added HTTPS outbound calls in the security group as a rule. The problem went away, allowing the Scheduler to call itself (.asmx webservice) to get data. Any firewall could cause this, an easy way to check is to see, if you can load the web application locally on the web server.

Hope this helps someone else having a similar issue.